# Qt Record Audio in Console Application

Tags: c++, qt, audio-recording

**I'm trying to create a console application records audio.**

But `QAudioDeviceInfo` always return null for defaultDevice.

When I call `QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput)` it returns a List with 0 element.

Is it possible record audio from Qt library in Console application? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you have the Qt Multimedia lib installed and included (`QT += multimedia` in your *.pro file)?

Comment: Actually I double checked, Yes I Included it but problem is different.

When I build it on Ubuntu 18.04 (same .pro file) It works and gets audio data (Qt 5.11). But I'm in another distro now, it doesn't work. (Qt 5.7.1) (and LTS kernel 4.9).

Is there a problem about audio driver with Qt versions? Because I opened Audacity and Microphone works very well but Qt doesn't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh. It was not about Qt software problem.

---

**I must install this package:**

`sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins`

---

Now it works in both console and widget apps.